# Error : The "multi-part" identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join 2 tables and getting this error.

About schema: PK's are a.app_guid, s.space_guid, o.org_guid.

> The multi-part identifier "apps.space_guid" could not be bound

```
SELECT 
    a.app_guid,
    a.name,
    a.state,
    a.created_at,
    a.updated_at,
    deleted_at,
    a.space_guid,
    a.foundation,
    a.timestamp, 

    s.space_guid,
    s.name,
    s.created_at,
    s.updated_at,
    s.timestamp,
    s.foundation,
    s.org_guid, 

    o.org_guid,
    o.created_at,
    o.updated_at,
    o.name,
    o.timestamp,
    o.foundation
FROM 
    apps a, spaces s, organizations o
INNER JOIN 
    [spaces] ON [apps].[space_guid] = [spaces].[space_guid]
INNER JOIN 
    [organizations] ON [spaces].[org_guid] = [organizations].[org_guid]
```

The expected result will include a table where its all combine according to `space_guid` and `org_guid`

Comment: If you define an alias for a table then you have to use it. For instance replace `[apps].[space_guid]` with `a.[space_guid]`

Comment: Don't mix the old, deprecated "comma-separated tables in `FROM`" style with the new, **proper** ANSI JOIN style - use the **new**, proper ANSI style **only** - and don't join each of the tables twice......

Comment: its not working still the same error

Comment: Is this your actual code? Are you really cross joining 3 tables and then inner join 2 more? Don't you have a WHERE clause?

Comment: @forpas I just need to join everything together I don't need where clause

Comment: @Sam see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you want to cross join and inner join the tables.
You just messed the syntax.
Use this proper join syntax:

```
SELECT 
    a.app_guid,
    a.name,
    a.state,
    a.created_at,
    a.updated_at,
    deleted_at,
    a.space_guid,
    a.foundation,
    a.timestamp, 

    s.space_guid,
    s.name,
    s.created_at,
    s.updated_at,
    s.timestamp,
    s.foundation,
    s.org_guid, 

    o.org_guid,
    o.created_at,
    o.updated_at,
    o.name,
    o.timestamp,
    o.foundation
FROM 
    apps a
INNER JOIN 
    spaces s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
INNER JOIN 
    organizations o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
```

Comment: Got it awesome thank you :)